# Использование MVC в сравнении с MVVM

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-webforms

Давайте представим взаимодействие клиента с контроллером, при котором в разные моменты времени отключается интернет. Меня интересует, может ли при таком взаимодействии повредиться база данных? Обоснуйте ответ. Сравните с MVVM. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И MVC, и MVVM - это паттерны организации уровня представления (Presentation Layer).

Т.к. уровень представления с базой данных напрямую не работает, то вероятность повреждения базы данных (что бы вы под этим не подразумевали) никак не зависит от того, используется ли MVC или MVVM.

При использовании современных СУБД база данных может повредиться только при физическом повреждении носителя или памяти на сервере.